# Mechanism of mass inflation instability in black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

The maximally extended Penrose diagram for charged or spinning black holes includes wormholes leading to different universes. However, in reality, these wormholes are untraversable due to the mass inflation instability at the inner horizon. The phenomenon is described in the article 'Journey into a realistic black hole' but I haven't quite grasped the concept of positive and negative energy, outgoing and ingoing streams and the directions of time being different in each wormhole. Also why don't the streams just cancel out but instead stream past each other ? I would appreciate any help in giving a clear explanation about the mechanism presented in the article.
The article: [https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/realistic.html](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/insidebh/realistic.html)

Comment: Andrew Hamilton, the author of the article you cite has a free [general relativity textbook](https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/courses/astr5770_18/grbook.pdf) that goes into this in some detail in sect. 21.6. You might also look at original research paper by [Poisson & Israel, 1989](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.1663), [free pdf](https://blackholes.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/gritting/pdf/black_holes/Poisson-Israel_Internal-structure-of-black-holes-and-Inner-horizon-instability-and-mass-inflation-in-black-holes.pdf).

Comment: I find the math quite a bit above my level since I'm not a Physics Major. Can you please give me a more 'intuitive' explanation ?

Comment: Let me ask: the mass inflation phenomenon actually means that a little extra mass causes a positive feedback at the inner horizon that produces a mass, ergo energy, diverging to infinity. But where does this huge energy and mass come from? Without going into the black hole from the outside. It's a serious violation of conservation of energy, isn't it? Do the authors of the hypothesis give any answer to this?